# CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. RazorPay Payment Gateway

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, cors

"I am working on my flight booking web application. For the payment gateway, I am using Razorpay (test mode). Locally, it's running fine, but when I deploy the API and then try to use the web app, everything works except when I try to access the payment gateway.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nqN2y.png)

This is my index.js - Express.js code:

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const cors = require("cors");
require("dotenv").config();
const port = process.env.PORT;
const mongoose = require("./config/mongoose");
const passport = require("passport");
const passportJWT = require("./config/passport-jwt-authentication");
const Razorpay = require("razorpay");

const corsOptions = {
  origin: "*",
  optionsSuccessStatus: 200,
};

app.use(cors(corsOptions));

module.exports.razorpayInstance = new Razorpay({
  key_id: process.env.RAZORPAY_API_KEY,

  key_secret: process.env.RAZORPAY_API_SECRECT,
});

app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

app.use("/", require("./routes"));

app.listen(port, (err) => {
  if (err) {
    console.log(`Error in running the server: ${err}`);
  }

  console.log(`Server is running on port: ${port}`);
});
```

This is the code for Payment Controller:

```
const { razorpayInstance } = require("..");
const crypto = require("crypto");
require("dotenv").config();
const Payment = require("../models/Payment");

module.exports.createOrder = async (req, res) => {
  let { totalAmmount } = req.body;
  totalAmmount = Number(totalAmmount * 100);

  const options = {
    amount: totalAmmount,
    currency: "INR",
  };
  const order = await razorpayInstance.orders.create(options);

  //   console.log(order);

  res.status(200).json({
    success: true,
    order,
  });
};

module.exports.paymentVarification = async (req, res) => {
  const { razorpay_payment_id, razorpay_order_id, razorpay_signature } =
    req.body;
  const hmac = crypto.createHmac("sha256", process.env.RAZORPAY_API_SECRECT);

  hmac.update(razorpay_order_id + "|" + razorpay_payment_id);
  let generatedSignature = hmac.digest("hex");

  let isSignatureValid = generatedSignature === razorpay_signature;

  if (isSignatureValid) {
    await Payment.create({
      razorpay_payment_id,
      razorpay_order_id,
      razorpay_signature,
    });
    res.redirect(
      `http://localhost:5173/paymentsuccess?paymentId=${razorpay_payment_id}`
    );
  } else {
    res.status(400).json({
      success: false,
      message: "Signature verification failed",
    });
  }
};

module.exports.getRazorpayAPIKEY = async (req, res) => {
  res.status(200).json({
    apiKey: process.env.RAZORPAY_API_KEY,
  });
};
```

This is the the fronend code:

```
export const checkOut = (passengerData, totalAmmount) => {
  return async (dispatch) => {
    const paymentRequest = async () => {
      const { data } = await axios.get(`${apiUrl}/api/payment/getAPI_KEY`);
      const response = await axios.post(`${apiUrl}/api/payment/createOrder`, {
        totalAmmount,
      });
      const options = {
        key: data.apiKey,
        amount: response.data.order.amount,
        currency: "INR",
        name: "JetSetGo",
        description: "Test Transaction",
        image: "https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/128/5333/5333722.png",
        order_id: response.data.order.id,
        callback_url: `${apiUrl}/api/payment/paymentVarification`,
        prefill: {
          name: passengerData.name,
          email: passengerData.email,
          contact: passengerData.phNo,
        },
        notes: {
          address: "JetSetGo Office ",
        },
        theme: {
          color: "#145214",
        },
      };

      return options;
    };

    try {
      const options = await paymentRequest();
      const rzp1 = new window.Razorpay(options);
      rzp1.open();
    } catch (error) {
      showNotification({
        status: "error",
        title: "Error!",
        message: "Conform request failed",
      });
      console.log(error);
    }
  };
};
```

**Please tell me what should I do to get rid of this error **

Comment: so, `apiUrl` is that `https://jetsetgo-backend-prodution.up.railway.app` ? and that's the one you've shown the `express` code for? the `503` status suggests a server is down

Comment: // config.js
const config = {
  development: {
    apiUrl: "http://localhost:8000",
  },
  production: {
    apiUrl: "https://jetsetgo-backend-production.up.railway.app",
  },
};

export default config;


this is apiUrl

Comment: so, the express code you posted is running up there on `jetsetgo-backend-prodution.up.railway.app`?

Comment: Yeah. When I was using the API locally ( localhost:8000) everything worked fine. But after deployment, these errors are showing

Comment: I'm not familiar with deploying server code to `railway.app` - I take it you've done it correctly - see, when you go to `https://etsetgo-backend-prodution.up.railway.app/` it says there is nothing there yet

Comment: Everything working fine after deployment too. Like I can fetch user , flights etc. But only the payment integration part is giving error. So there should not be any problem in deployment.

Comment: So other requests to `/api` work, just not `/api/payment` - again, not familiar with how `railway.app` works, so perhaps I should stop since I have no clue

Comment: /api/payment works locally though.

and the same error in the render deployment also.

Comment: "works locally" doesn't mean you've configured the production server correctly

Comment: Hey the problem is resolved now.
U were right I made one mistake while putting my env values. That was the reason.

Thanks